# Manhua with a female lead who has red hair and is constantly reviving through a system In order to finish tasks

Tags: story-identification, manga

It has a female lead who had red hair, at least at some point or another, and is part of this system. The system will give her a task or job that she must complete in order to leave that world and/or life. She has to collect a certain amount of these lives or jobs in order to be free.

She goes through this process many times during the story and has this little animal that gives her the next job that she has to do. I remember it have quite a few chapters/arcs.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?  Do you recall the names of any of the characters or places she visits?

Comment: I’m not sure but I read it a very long time ago, maybe even a year but no later than a year and a half. I remember there were some life’s that were modern and some that weren’t. I know that one was set in a “historical” setting and another was modern such as I think they might have been a pop star or some sort of actor. Another life she was a high schooler. One life she was a stay at home wife with a cheating husband. My memory is kinda foggy to be honest. I read it on a website that had these sort of stories, to which website I can’t remember.

Comment: The combination of "female protagonist", "system", "perform jobs" and "multiple arcs" makes me think of Cheating Men Must Die. I haven't read it so I can't confirm any of the other details. Is this the story you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, thank you! You got it! I’d already found it while searching earlier but thank you for your response! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As confirmed in the comments, this is *[Cheating Men Must Die](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/cheating-men-must-die)*.

> One moment oppressing scum yields a moment of satisfaction. Continuously oppressing scum yields continuous satisfaction. Our female main lead, Su Lüxia is bound to the Female Lead Counterattack System and **transmigrates to several small worlds**. Using elaborate means, she beats up countless cheating bastards and bitches. Su Lüxia: "Only a cheating bastard's tears of remorse, and the pained moans of a bitch unable to get what she wants bring me solace." System: "Has my host tapped into her humanity today? Nope."